# linear transformation- cant continue the proof

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

as part of studying for an exam i encountered a proof question:

Let vector spaces $U,V$ over a field $F$ and Linear maps $T,S:U\rightarrow V$ be given.

Prove that there exist bases $B_1$,$B_2$ of $U$ and $C_1,C_2$ of $V$ such that $[T]$ from $B_1$ to $C_1$ = $[S]$ from $B_2$ to $C_2$  if and only if $rank(T)=rank(S)$.
Here the rank of a linear map is defined as the dimension of its image: $rank(T)=dim(Im(T))$.

I know that in order to prove this i need to show both ways.

for the first way, i know that if $[T]=[S]$ than it doesnt matter in in what basis the matrixes are, the ranks of the matrixes will be equal, therefore $rank(T)=rank(S)$.

for the other way, i know that $rank(T)=rank(S)$ $\Rightarrow$ $dim(Im(T))=dim(Im(S))$ $\Rightarrow$ from the rank-nullity theorom i will know that $dim(ker(T))=dim(ker(S))$.

from the point that the dimensions of the kernels are equal i dont know how to continue the proof. i would like someone to continue the proof for me. and i dont know if the first way is true as well so if someine can tell me if it is true

Answer (score 1):

For such $T,S:U\to V$, if $\text{rank}(T)=\text{rank}(S)=n$, choose two ordered bases of $Im(T)$ and $Im(S)$, denoted as $\mathcal{B}_1=\{b_0,..,b_{n-1}\}$ and $\mathcal{B}_2=\{b_0',...,b_{n-1}'\}$. Choose $c_i$ and $c_i'$ s.t. $T(c_i)=b_i$ and $T(c_i')=b_i'$. I claim that $\{c_i\}_{i\leq n-1}$ and $\{c_i'\}_{i\leq n-1}$ are both independent sets (why?). Extend them to be basis of $U$ if they are not and make sure new $c_i$ and $c_i'$ satisfy $T(c_i)=T(c_i')=0$ when you extend it. Denote these two basis as $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ respectively. Then, the matrix representation of $T$ under $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $S$ under $\mathcal{B}_2$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ are the same, because the two linear maps have the same rank (that is a matrix with 1 in the first $\text{rank}(T)=\text{rank}(S)$ many entries of diagonal and all other entries are zero).

For the other direction, note that basis change cannot alter the dimension of a matrix representation, so if $T$ and $S$ have different ranks, the matrix representation cannot be the same.

Comment: you claimed that dim(T)=dim(S), why is that? because i found out that dim(ker(T))=dim(ker(S)) and we also know that dim(Im(T))=dim(Im(S))?

Comment: and can u explain why ci and c'i are independent sets for sure?

Comment: The first paragraph is about assuming dim(T)=dim(S) and prove that they can have the same matrix representation under different basises. The second is about assuming dim(T) not equal to dim(S) and showing that T and S cannot have the same matrix representations under any basises.

Comment: If c_i (or c_i') are not independent, by the property of linear map, you can show that B_1 (or B_2) are not independent, so they cannot be basis, contradiction.

Comment: but we know that rank(T)=rank(S), how from that you are assuming that dim(T)=dim(S)?

Comment: That's a typo. I thought that you defined dim(T) to be dim(Im(T)).

Comment: can you also explain why there will be only 1s and 0s for sure?

Comment: I added one line to explain it in the answer (in the end of the 4-th line). Make sure to choose special basis when you extend it. And I claim that if you choose basis of ker(T) (and ker(S)) to extend it, that will be enough. This is because Ker(T)+(U/Ker(T))=U is in direct sum, so the dimension is just the sum of them.

Comment: As for why the matrix representaiton is of that form, note that [T]^B_C=([T(c_1)]_B, [T(c_2)]_B,...,[T(c_m)]_B). That's how [f]^B_C is computed and defined.

Comment: so if you will look at my try for solution, at the sentence "for the other way..." this is not the right approach? i cant continue in this method?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at it. Let me see.

Comment: Rank–nullity theorem is exactly what I meant by Ker(T)+(U/Ker(T))=U is direct sum, so feel free to replace it. In your proof of "for the other way", that's not enough, because you need to select explicitly the basises satisfying xxxxx. In this part, you can refer to my way of selection.

Comment: ok got you, thank you very much for all the help

Comment: No problem. Note that my proof also shows the existence and uniqueness of Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Hi, can i write here another question that i will like help in? because the website doesnt allow to post more than 2 questions in a day

Comment: thank you' i sent you an email

Comment: it actually says that your email is incorect

Answer (score 0):

Possibly overkill if you don't know the SVD:

By the [singular value decomposition (SVD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), there exists orthonormal bases $B_1, B_2$ of $U$ and $C'_1, C'_2$ such that $[T]_{B_1, C'_1}$ and $[S]_{B_2, C'_2}$ are [[rectangular] diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Definition) with nonnegative entries on the diagonal, called singular values. These diagonal entries can be assumed to be nonincreasing, and the number of nonzero entries is the rank of the matrix.

By scaling the basis vectors of $C'_1$ and $C'_2$ by the corresponding singular values, you can get new (no longer orthonormal) bases $C_1, C_2$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{B_1, C_1}$ and $[S]_{B_2, C_2}$ are diagonal matrices whose diagonal entries are $1$s and $0$s (in nondecreasing order). Since the number of $1$s is the rank of each matrix, the two matrices must be the same.

---

Sketch of alternate solution:

Applying row operations to a matrix (e.g., Gaussian elimination) is equivalent to modifying a basis for the codomain $V$. In particular, if you know Gaussian elimination can bring a matrix into RREF form, then you immediately know that there exists a basis $C_1$ for the codomain $V$ for which the matrix of $T$ is in RREF form. Similarly, column operations are equivalent to modifying a basis for the domain $U$. You can apply column operations to the RREF matrix to obtain a rectangular diagonal matrix with only $1$s and $0$s, where the number of $1$s is the rank of $T$, so there exists a basis $B_1$ for $U$ (along with the basis $B_2$ for $V$) such that the matrix of $T$ is this kind of matrix. Doing the same for $S$ will bring you to the same matrix since their ranks are the same.

Comment: sorry, i dont know what SVD is and i didnt study the material that you used here

Comment: @RonenDvorkin See my edit.

Comment: first of all thanks for the respond, can you please explain why there will be only 1s and 0s after the doing operations?

Comment: @RonenDvorkin In RREF form, the pivots elements are $1$. You can then use column operations to eliminate the non-pivot elements.

Comment: so if you will look at my try for solution, at the sentence "for the other way..." this is not the right approach? i cant continue in this method?

Comment: @RonenDvorkin Your attempt so far has correct statements, but I don't see how this will lead to constructions of the 4 bases. I'm not saying it's impossible though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117875/discussion-between-ronen-dvorkin-and-angryavian).