# Prove that for linear $T,S:U\mapsto V$, if rank($T$)=rank($S$) then there are bases $B,D$ of $U$ and $C,E$ of V for which: $[T]_C^B$=$[S]_E^D$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm out of ideas. I'd appreciate if someone could help with this proof.
I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but I wanted to base my proof on the fact that since rank(T)=rank(S), this means that $rankC[T]_C^B$ = $rankC[S]_E^D$. Then there is the same number of columns that are linearly independent in both matrices, which means we can expand them to become bases... and then use a matrix to change bases. I feel like it doesn't make much sense, so I would like someone to write his proof.

Comment: I answered a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967080/linear-transformation-cant-continue-the-proof) a few days ago...

Answer (score 1):

For $B$, start with a basis of the kernel of $T$, and complete it to a basis of $U$.

For $C$, start with the non-zero images of the elements of $B$, and complete to a basis of $V$.

Then
$$
[T]^{B}_{C}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \dots  & 0 & 0\\
  &   &   & \ddots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0& 0\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where the number of $1$'s equals the rank of $T$.

Comment: This question is part of my final grade, so I want to be absolutely sure in the proof I present. Just making sure: And the same should be done to the linear transformation S, obviously, and thus I show that the matrices I get are equal? I have to admit that this proof is so straight-forward compared to others I've seen. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's as you say. And then you should fill in a detail, that is, shoe the non-zero images of the elements of $B$ are linearly independent; but this is a straightforward calculation that you've probably already seen in the proof of rank-nullity.